# Error on using Entity Framework on released winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I used entity framework V6 in win form App.
I have correct connection string in App.config

but when I made setup package and install on a client machine I got this error.

```
"No connection string named 'MyEntities1' could be found in the application config file."
```

Comment: Check your `app.config` and `web.config`. Check if there's a connecting string with this name there.

Comment: :). The error is self explanatory. Since you are using winforms, make sure your `app.config` file has the connectionStrings section with a connectionString of same name

Comment: the app.config file in the project solution has the right connection string but released app can not find connection string.

Comment: I recommend to hard code the connection string in the program code itself. it is more secure  and no such errors. to do that pass the connection string to the `EF data context` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppConfig is originally gets created in the project that we generate the entity model. But if you are executing the application using some other project, the AppConfig needs to be included in the project which is being executed.

You can also try this example try doing the changes as mentioned below name of entities should be changed as per your ef configuration.

```
 public MasterEntities()
        : base("name=MyApplicationEntities")
    {
    }


to 
 public MasterEntities()
        : base("MyApplicationEntities")
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your startup project (Project name is in bold if you're using Visual Studio) you should have a file named App.config and the file should contain the following section:

```
<configuration>
   <!-- ... some other app specific configurations -->

    <connnectionStrings>
     <add name="MyEntities1" connectionString="yourConnectionString"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```